# How to dynamically move <tr> into a newly created <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<table id="j_idt28:innerContent" class="innerContent">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      .......
      <tr>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The  tags are being populated with a parsed XML response.

I usually have 20 or so tr tags.
I want that after the 4th, 8th, 12, etc  tag to create a  and insert the 4  tags into it.

Here is my jquery so far:

```
var i = 1;
var j = 2;
var margin = 0;
var max = $('.innerContent tr').length;
  for(i = 1; i<=max; i++)
  {
  var child1 =  i - 3;
  var child2 =  i - 2;
  var child3 =  i - 1;
  var hotel1 =  $('.innerContent tr:nth-child('+child1+')');
  var hotel2 =  $('.innerContent tr:nth-child('+child2+')');
  var hotel3 =  $('.innerContent tr:nth-child('+child3+')');
  var hotel4 =  $('.innerContent tr:nth-child('+i+')');
    if(i%4 == 0)
    {
    $('.innerContent tbody').prepend('<div class="line_wrapper"></div>');
    $('.line_wrapper').append(hotel1,hotel2,hotel3,hotel4);
}
  }
  for(j =2; j<=max ;j++)
  {
  var hotel =  $('.innerContent tr:nth-child('+j+')');
    margin = margin + 280;
    hotel.css('margin-left',margin+'px');
    //$('.line_wrapper').append(hotel);
  }
```

This just does not quite work as I would have expected. I want to add the divs in order for me to use bootstrap fluid layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using each:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function (i) {
    i%4?$(this).prev('div').append(this):$(this).wrap('<div/>');
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed, and it's a lot shorter :D. Thank you !